# Conditionally displaying block

Tags: magento2, login, ifconfig

I have a block that replaces the default Magento login form. I would like to conditionally display it, or else revert to the default login form. I am using `ifconfig` to display the block if a certain configuration variable is set:

```
<block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Form\LoginFormClass" name="module_form_login" template="Module::login_page.phtml" ifconfig="module_config/login/enable">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="display" xsi:type="string">embed</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

However, what this does is just hide or show the block. When the configuration is disabled, the block is hidden, but the default Magento login form does not appear. The `customer_account_login.xml` has additional elements (referenceContainer/referenceBlock etc.) that don't have a valid `ifconfig` parameter.

Is it possible to only activate the entire override conditionally, and display the default login form if the condition is not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="module_config/login/enable">
                <argument name="text" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::login_page.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the correct way, but I need to actually replace a referenceContainer (customer.login.container), because the registration functionality is also replaced. It doesn't like the `action` tag however. Do you know how to do it with the container? Thanks again.

Comment: If you have new question, then ask seprately.

Comment: Although it's essentially the same concept, I have asked a new question specifically about containers, please have a look: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239188/conditionally-removing-a-container

Comment: Ok I will look into that as well.