# Conditionally removing a container

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account, containers

I am trying to replace the `customer.login.container` on the login page, which can be done through `customer_account_login.xml` by adding something like:

```
<referenceContainer name="customer.login.container" remove="true" />
```

However, I need to set a config condition (similar to `ifconfig` for blocks), where I will remove this container if a certain config is true, and replace it with another container/blocks. If the config is false, the original page should remain untouched.

I have tried overriding the `toHtml` method in the login class, but get strange results and it's probably not the best way to do this. Is it possible to do this through the XML files alone? If not, what's the most harmless way to intervene here without removing existing Magento functionality or creating an observer / any kind of action that waits for the original container to load and only then makes changes?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be technically possible, even though this solution is not ideal IMO because it removes the container in a different place than the other layout definitions usually take place, and it feels like a bad hack. I hope someone can give a better answer.

The method is this: it's necessary to override `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`'s `_toHtml()` method. The way to disable the container is through `AbstractBlock::unsetElement()`. For example:

```
if ($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('module/section/config', 'website') === 'relevant_value')
{
    $this->getLayout()->unsetElement('customer.login.container');
}
return parent::_toHtml();
```